# Swift using estimatedItemSize for cell breaks cell width during scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview

ios version 11/12

Trying to make dynamic cell height for `UIViewController` (cell contains image with fixed height and label that can be multiline because of that label view-cell should be able dynamically change height). I'm using Storyboard to construct basic UI with some constrains that makes cell min width 300.

Getting strange UI behaviour during vertical scrolling in UIViewController. Some cells(that are not in the UI initially) resized to the size defined in Storyboard constrains and ignoring `estimatedItemSize`

```swift
import UIKit

class StartController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let offers = SearchCategoryOffer.mockOffers
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let titleImageView = NavigationImageView()
        titleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "logo")
        navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView

        let w = self.collectionView.frame.width - 30

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.sectionInsetReference = .fromLayoutMargins
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 5, 20, 5)
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 26
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
            layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: w, height: 300) // cell size
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return offers.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell: OfferCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! OfferCell
        cell.listTitle?.text = offers[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let _: OfferCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! OfferCell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let _: OfferCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! OfferCell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // bla-bla-bla
    }
}

class NavigationImageView: UIImageView {
    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 133, height: 35)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything about estimatedItemSize in your code. I don't use storyboards so maybe you have it there, but that means they are had-coded. Maybe a page from my book on TableViews might help: Typically I grab the actual size of the cell when it is presented and store it in a dictionary with UUIIDs or server IDs as keys (not the index path). Then I reuse these values as the estimates.  This gives me much better results and removes glitches while scrolling and reloading a table view. Maybe this will work help on collection views as well.

Comment: @Kubee `layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: w, height: 300) // cell size
`